# Laravel Eloquent one to many relation filter with multiple criteria

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, model, eloquent

**Works**

```
$comments = App\Post::find(1)->comments()->where('title', 'foo');
```

**This does not work**

```
$comments = App\Post::where('id', '=', $id)
->where('column', '=', $val)
->comments()->where('title', 'foo');
```

Expecting to get collection of model filtered by `id` and `column`

Answer (score 1):

Probably you're getting a `undefined method` error. You're trying to call `comments()` on the Eloquent Builder class. This will fix your problem.

```
$comments = App\Post::where('id', '=', $id)
    ->where('column', '=', $val)
    ->where('title', 'foo')
    ->first()->comments;
```

Answer (score 0):

The where clause does not return a collection, you should first get a collection after which you can apply further clauses.

I.e.:

```
$comments = App\Post::where('column', $val)
  ->where('id', $id)
  ->first()
  ->comments
  ->where('title', 'foo');
```

Furthermore `'='` is the default for a `where` clause and thus they can be omitted.

Comment: `$comments = App\Post::where('column', '=', $val)
  ->find($id)` returning null. Any way to see the raw query?

Comment: @varuog something like [this](https://www.goodbytes.be/article/log-last-executed-eloquent-query-as-plain-sql-in-laravel-5) might help with that

Answer (score 0):

You can add additional queries to a relationship with [`Model::with()`](https://laravel.com/api/5.2/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_with) ([laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads)), to contrain the returning elements:

```
$comments = App\Post::where("id", $id)
    ->where("column", $val)
    ->with(["comments" => function ($query) {
        $query->where("title", "foo");
    }])
    ->first()
    ->comments;
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you try to access model function you need object of the model class.

In the first case, You have got model object, So you can add query after that so works perfectly.

In the second case,

```
App\Post::where('id', '=', $id)
          ->where('column', '=', $val)
          ->comments()
          ->where('title', 'foo');
```

You need to get `Post` object before you apply model function `comments()`. But here, you are getting Query Builder. So you can't apply model function on it.

You can use `find()` or `first()` function if only row you are searching for.

In case of multiple results, not a good solution but you can iterate over for loop.

```
$posts = App\Post::where('id',$id)
         ->where('column',$val)
         ->get();

foreach($posts as post){
   // Acess like $post->comments
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have relationships, you can include [Eager Loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) and pass a function to add conditions to your query, for example:

```
$comments = App\Post::with([‘comments’ => function($query) { 
                $query->where(‘title’, ‘foo’);
            }])->where(‘column’, $val)->find($id);
```